# Javascript - How to convert and download base64 pdf data as an png image?

Tags: javascript, pdf, base64, png

I want to tricker a png file download with base64 pdf data. How to do so? That's my script:

```
var base64pdfData = atob(
  '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');

var obj = document.createElement('object');
obj.style.width = '100%';
obj.style.height = '842pt';
obj.type = 'image/png';
obj.data = 'data:image/png;base64,' + base64pdfData;
document.body.appendChild(obj); 

var link = document.createElement('a');
link.innerHTML = 'Download PNG file';
link.download = 'file.png';
link.href = 'data:application/octet-stream;base64,' + base64pdfData;
document.body.appendChild(link);

//var a = document.createElement("a"); //Create <a>
//a.href = "data:image/png;base64," + base64pdfData; //Image Base64 Goes   here
//a.download = "Image.png"; //File name Here
//a.click();
```

Here is a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/duejg9n3/

Do I need to use this pdf.js library? https://jsfiddle.net/pdfjs/cq0asLqz/

Comment: *I want to tricker a png file* - sorry, but what does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to do two things before you can download a PNG image:

1. Decode the base64 string to obtain the PDF
2. Convert the PDF to PNG

One way to do this is through using something like the [LEADTOOLS Document Library](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/document) (which is what I am familiar with since I work for the vendor of this toolkit).

Using this library, you can be implement the DocumentConverter class in a server-side C# code that decodes the base64 string, converts PDF to PNG, then returns the PNG output in a base64 string:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(pdfStr));
using (DocumentConverter documentConverter = new DocumentConverter())
using (LEADDocument document = DocumentFactory.LoadFromStream(ms, new LoadDocumentOptions()))
{
   MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream();

   DocumentConverterJobData jobData = new DocumentConverterJobData();
   jobData.Document = document;
   jobData.RasterImageFormat = RasterImageFormat.Png;
   jobData.OutputDocumentStream = outputStream;
   jobData.JobName = "Convert to PNG Job";
   DocumentConverterJob job = documentConverter.Jobs.CreateJob(jobData);
   documentConverter.Jobs.RunJob(job);

   pngStr = Convert.ToBase64String(outputStream.ToArray());
}
```